# Ocr can't recognize a specific image

Tags: ocr

I am seeking to make these images [image],
[image] (8,0) recognized by an Ocr 
I am using tesseract but i don't mind if another Ocr make it

Answer (score 1):

We should call tesseract with option `-psm <N>` for the page setup:

```
0 = Orientation and script detection (OSD) only.
1 = Automatic page segmentation with OSD.
2 = Automatic page segmentation, but no OSD, or OCR.
3 = Fully automatic page segmentation, but no OSD. (Default)
4 = Assume a single column of text of variable sizes.
5 = Assume a single uniform block of vertically aligned text.
6 = Assume a single uniform block of text.
7 = Treat the image as a single text line.
8 = Treat the image as a single word.
9 = Treat the image as a single word in a circle.
10 = Treat the image as a single character.
```

The options of interest are `10` and `6` in case we only have a single character in our bitmap source.

By rendering the [gray image source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO1v5.png) as follows

```
tesseract LO1v5.png -psm 6
```

we will get a correct result of `8`, but the [green image source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqIhI.png) is too much of a challenge for tesseract which is specialized on whole texts rather than numbers.

By improving the input quality

[image] [image]

we will get better results on calling tesseract in single character recognizing mode:

```
tesseract sourceimage -psm 10
```

This will give us a correct guess of `8` but only an almost correct guess of `B` for the `0`-image.